# Client sends RST to recieved packets after shutdown(SHUT_WR)

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming

After closing the writing direction of a connection of a socket using `shutdown()` all subsequently received data causes an RST packet to be sent and `read()` returns a size of 0 indicating EOF for the reading direction. Why is this the case, even though the reading direction wasn't closed?

Using wireshark I checked the sent packets:

```
No. Time     Source        Destination   Protocol Length Info
1   0.000000 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  TCP      78     55318 → 80 [SYN] Seq=0 Win=65535 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=32
2   0.114608 3.85.154.144  192.168.0.175 TCP      74     80 → 55318 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=26847 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256
3   0.114706 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  TCP      66     55318 → 80 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=131744 Len=0
4   0.115371 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  HTTP     112    GET /bytes/512 HTTP/1.1 
5   0.115401 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  TCP      66     55318 → 80 [FIN, ACK] Seq=47 Ack=1 Win=131744 Len=0
6   0.222652 3.85.154.144  192.168.0.175 TCP      66     80 → 55318 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=47 Win=26880 Len=0
7   0.224444 3.85.154.144  192.168.0.175 HTTP     801    HTTP/1.1 200 OK  (application/octet-stream)
8   0.224543 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  TCP      54     55318 → 80 [RST] Seq=48 Win=0 Len=0
9   0.226056 3.85.154.144  192.168.0.175 TCP      66     80 → 55318 [FIN, ACK] Seq=736 Ack=48 Win=26880 Len=0
10  0.226100 192.168.0.175 3.85.154.144  TCP      54     55318 → 80 [RST] Seq=48 Win=0 Len=0
```

After the [FIN, ACK] is sent, all received data is responded to with RSTs. It seems like the local side is thinking the connection is fully closed even though a FIN was sent (indicating the end of written data) instead of an RST (indicating the end of the connection). The remote side expects to be able to send data, but can't.
Monitoring the socket status with netstat reveals that the connection is instantly fully closed after `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR)` is called.

Here's a MWE in C++. It assumes all non-relevant functions succeed and aborts otherwise. The return codes of all functions are checked for errors to make sure they aren't at fault for the results.

```cpp
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define RUN_OR_ABORT(fun) {\
    int RETVAL = fun;\
    if (RETVAL == -1)\
    {\
        perror(#fun);\
        abort();\
    }\
}

int main() {
    // Establish connection to httpbin.org:80
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (sockfd == -1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    // "httpbin.org" resolves to 3.85.154.144 or 52.71.234.219
    int retcode = inet_pton(addr.sin_family, "3.85.154.144", &addr.sin_addr);
    if (retcode != 1) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    RUN_OR_ABORT(connect(sockfd, (sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)));

    // Request 512 random bytes
    const char* msg = "GET /bytes/512 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\n\r\n";
    ssize_t write_len = write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    if (write_len != strlen(msg)) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    RUN_OR_ABORT(shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR));

    // Prepare buffer for recieving data
    size_t buf_size = 1024, read_offset = 0;
    char* buf = new char[buf_size];

    // Read as long as there is data available
    while (true) {
        ssize_t read_len = read(sockfd, buf + read_offset, buf_size - read_offset);
        if (read_len == -1 and (errno & (EAGAIN | EINTR)))
            continue;
        else if (read_len == -1) {
            perror("recv()");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        read_offset += read_len;
        if (read_len == 0) {
            // EOF?
            printf("%lu bytes have been read\n", read_offset);
            break;
        }
        if (read_offset >= buf_size) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Unexpectedly large response\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected the `read()` call to return a non-zero size and the socket to remain open for reading after closing the writing end with `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR)`. The expected output of the MWE would be:

```
740 bytes have been read
```

(or similar, but the number of read bytes should be bigger than 512 bytes).
The actual output was:

```
0 bytes have been read
```

Comment: Your log No. 7 shows you that you receive the data, no?

Comment: It is because you didn't close the socket in the client. However the whole scheme is incorrect. You shouldn't be using shutdowns with HTTP. You should have sent a `Content-length` of zero so the server knew when to stop reading the request, and a `Connection: close` to tell it not to use HTTP keepalive.

Comment: Where is `read_offset` variable declared?

Comment: @NikolaiFetissov On the same line as `buf_size`.

Comment: @czorp yes, but it is rejected on No.8 with an RST and cannot be `read()` from the socket.

Comment: @kaka Do try it all again, but this time closing the socket, before you post again. You just wasted six hours.

Comment: Indeed your log looks strange for a write shutdown. It looks more like you have performed a `close()` (FIN and then only RST) to me. I cant confirm this behavior on my machine, it is just working fine here...

Comment: @user207421 http GET with Content-length of 0?, first time I would see something like this.

Comment: @czorp I do not understand your comment. All HTTP GETs should have a `Content-length` (which would normally be zero), unless they specify `Connection: close`.

Comment: @user207421 According to [RFC 7230, section 3.3.2: Content-Length](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2): *A user agent SHOULD NOT send a Content-Length header field when the request message does not contain a payload body and the method semantics do not anticipate such a body.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is a (misbehaving) transparent HTTP proxy. Avast's Web Shield intercepts packets before they are sent or received and inspects them for Malware. Avast uses seperate internal sockets for this. As soon as the first FIN is sent, Avast (incorrectly) closes its internal socket. This is communicated to the client's socket, which is why it doesn't show up in netstat afterwards. The server's data is then rejected, because Avast's socket, which is responsible for handling incoming data is no longer open.
Avast's strategy of closing the connection on the first FIN packet (without telling the server about it; There is no RST packet until data is received) works, because almost all HTTP clients never call `shutdown(sockfd, SHUT_WR)` and only `close()` the connection, when there is no more data to be read.

Comment: Does it do this even if you don't claim HTTP 1.1 compliance? You specifically said it wasn't an HTTP-specific issue when I suggested that it was and you're saying that it is HTTP specific.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I mistakenly assumed the issue wasn't HTTP-specific (It is HTTP/1.1-specific and doesn't work on HTTP/1.0 with keep-alive). But the client is actually HTTP/1.1-compliant (to the best of my knowledge). RFC 7230 labels the 'Connection: close' Header with a 'SHOULD' and not a 'MUST' ([source](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.6)) and even states that connections may be closed at any time, although it doesn't specify what should happen if a connection is half-closed by the client.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the HTTP/1.1 standard allows this behavior. Since it breaks your code, your code is not HTTP/1.1 compliant.

Comment: The issue is that you misused shutdown, which isn't part of the HTTP protocol, and failed to close the socket in your client, which caused the operating system to reset the connection.